# What is the difference between Int and Integer?

Tags: haskell, numbers, integer, int, bignum

In Haskell, what is the difference between an `Int` and an `Integer`? Where is the answer documented?

Answer (score 216, accepted):

> "Integer" is an arbitrary precision
>   type: it will hold any number no
>   matter how big, up to the limit of
>   your machine's memory…. This means you never have
>   arithmetic overflows. On the other
>   hand it also means your arithmetic is
>   relatively slow. Lisp users may
>   recognise the "bignum" type here.
>
> "Int" is the more common 32 or 64 bit
>   integer. Implementations vary,
>   although it is guaranteed to be at
>   least 30 bits.

Source: [The Haskell Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/A_Miscellany_of_Types). Also, you may find the [Numbers](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/numbers.html) section of *A Gentle Introduction to Haskell* useful.

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3646472/673206), using `Integer` is often faster than is

Comment: @Maarten, that's only because `Int64` is implemented rather badly on 32-bit systems. On 64-bit systems, it's great.

Answer (score 27):

`Int` is `Bounded`, which means that you can use `minBound` and `maxBound` to find out the limits, which are implementation-dependent but guaranteed to hold at least [-2<sup>29</sup>  .. 2<sup>29</sup>-1].

For example:

```
Prelude> (minBound, maxBound) :: (Int, Int)
(-9223372036854775808,9223372036854775807)
```

However, `Integer` is arbitrary precision, and not `Bounded`.

```
Prelude> (minBound, maxBound) :: (Integer, Integer)

<interactive>:3:2:
    No instance for (Bounded Integer) arising from a use of `minBound'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Bounded Integer)
    In the expression: minBound
    In the expression: (minBound, maxBound) :: (Integer, Integer)
    In an equation for `it':
        it = (minBound, maxBound) :: (Integer, Integer)
```

Answer (score 22):

> *Int* is the type of machine integers,
>   with guaranteed range at least
>   -2<sup>29</sup> to 2<sup>29</sup> - 1, while *Integer* is arbitrary precision integers, with
>   range as large as you have memory for.

https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2005-May/009906.html

Answer (score 11):

Int is the C int, which means its values range from -2147483647 to 2147483647, 
while an Integer range from the whole **Z** set, that means, it can be arbitrarily large.

```
$ ghci
Prelude> (12345678901234567890 :: Integer, 12345678901234567890 :: Int)
(12345678901234567890,-350287150)
```

Notice the value of the Int literal.

Comment: GHCi, version 7.10.3 gives warning :  Literal 12345678901234567890 is out of the Int range -9223372036854775808..9223372036854775807

Answer (score 5):

> The Prelude defines only the most
>   basic numeric types: fixed sized
>   integers (Int), arbitrary precision
>   integers (Integer), ...

...

> The finite-precision integer type Int
>   covers at least the range [ - 2^29,
>   2^29 - 1].

from the Haskell report: http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/basic.html#numbers

Answer (score 5):

An `Integer` is implemented as an `Int#` until it gets larger than the maximum value an `Int#` can store. At that point, it's a [GMP](https://gmplib.org) number.

Comment: This sounds implementation specific. Is there a reference saying that Integer needs to be implemented this way?

Comment: No, you're right, this is GHC specific. That said, 1. GHC is what most people use, 2. This is the most intelligent way I can think of to implement such a data type.

Comment: Does this mean that (in GHC) there's no performance tradeoff for using `Integer`, and therefore `Integer` is always the better option?