# Different behaviour of Int and Integer?

Tags: haskell

The followng snippet contains a solution for [exercise 3 on page 69](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/defining-types-streamlining-functions.html#x_KC1) (write a function `mean` to calculate the mean of a list).

While writing some QuickCheck tests to verify whether the its results are more or less sane, I found that on my system (ghc 6.12.3, Haskell Platform 2010.2.0.0 on 32-but Ubuntu 10.4) the tests work for `Integer` inputs, but not for `Int` ones. Any idea on why?

```
import Test.QuickCheck

-- From text and previous exercises
data List a = Cons a (List a)
            | Nil
              deriving (Show)

fromList        :: [a] -> List a
fromList []     = Nil
fromList (x:xs) = Cons x (fromList xs)

listLength             :: List a -> Int
listLength Nil         = 0
listLength (Cons x xs) = 1 + listLength xs

-- Function ``mean`` is the aim of this exercise
mean             :: (Integral a) => List a -> Double
mean Nil         = 0
mean (Cons x xs) = (fromIntegral x + n * mean xs) / (n + 1)
    where n = fromIntegral (listLength xs)

-- To overcome rounding issues
almostEqual     :: Double -> Double -> Bool
almostEqual x y = (abs (x - y)) < 0.000001

-- QuickCheck tests for ``mean``
prop_like_arith_mean :: (Integral a) => [a] -> Property
prop_like_arith_mean xs = not (null xs) ==>
                          almostEqual
                          (mean (fromList xs))
                          (fromIntegral (sum xs) / fromIntegral (length xs))

prop_sum :: (Integral a) => [a] -> Bool
prop_sum xs = almostEqual
              (fromIntegral (length xs) * mean (fromList xs))
              (fromIntegral (sum xs))

-- This passes:
check_mean_ok =
    quickCheck (prop_like_arith_mean :: [Integer] -> Property) >>
    quickCheck (prop_sum :: [Integer] -> Bool)

-- This fails:
check_mean_fail =
    quickCheck (prop_like_arith_mean :: [Int] -> Property) >>
    quickCheck (prop_sum :: [Int] -> Bool)

main = check_mean_ok >>
       check_mean_fail
```

Comment: Completely irrelevant to the question, but your `mean` function looks very inefficient to me.  It calculates the length of the list at each step in the recursion, which means that this function will traverse the list much more than is necessary.  There are *many* discussions on how to optimize this; try looking through the haskell-cafe archives or read Conal Elliott's blog post on "Beautiful Folds".

Comment: @John: Thanks for the comment: I found http://squing.blogspot.com/2008/11/beautiful-folding.html following Conal's post, and it's been very enlightening!

Comment: thanks for that link.  My apologies to the original author; I was only familiar with Conal's followup and thus didn't give credit where it's due.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Haskell Int and Integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429291/haskell-int-and-integer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Int` is based on the underlying system's int implementation, and will probably the same lower and upper limits as the underlying system (but at least a range of [ -2^29, 2^29 - 1]. `Integer` has arbitrary precision. Therefore you might be seeing an overflow or underflow when you use `Int`.

Comment: Thanks, jball -- I had not thought about the over-/underflow