# How to improve the performance of this Haskell program?

Tags: c, performance, haskell

I'm working through the problems in [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/) as a way of learning Haskell, and I find that my programs are a lot slower than a comparable C version, even when compiled. What can I do to speed up my Haskell programs?

For example, my brute-force solution to [Problem 14](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=14) is:

```
import Data.Int
import Data.Ord
import Data.List

searchTo = 1000000

nextNumber :: Int64 -> Int64
nextNumber n
    | even n    = n `div` 2
    | otherwise = 3 * n + 1

sequenceLength :: Int64 -> Int
sequenceLength 1 = 1
sequenceLength n = 1 + (sequenceLength next)
    where next = nextNumber n

longestSequence = maximumBy (comparing sequenceLength) [1..searchTo]

main = putStrLn $ show $ longestSequence
```

Which takes around 220 seconds, while an "equivalent" brute-force C version only takes 1.2 seconds.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int longest = 0;
    int terms = 0;
    int i;
    unsigned long j;

    for (i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++)
    {
        j = i;
        int this_terms = 1;

        while (j != 1)
        {
            this_terms++;

            if (this_terms > terms)
            {
                terms = this_terms;
                longest = i;
            }

            if (j % 2 == 0)
                j = j / 2;
            else
                j = 3 * j + 1;
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", longest);
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Or am I naive to think that Haskell could even approach C's speed?

(I'm compiling the C version with gcc -O2, and the Haskell version with ghc --make -O).

Comment: Your `unsigned long` may be just 32-bit long. For fair comparison, use an `unsigned long long` or `uint64_t`.

Comment: @KennyTM - fair point - I was testing on 32-bit Ubuntu where a long happens to be 64-bits.

Comment: @stusmith: I see. That's fine then.

Comment: @stusmith: Are you sure about that? I could have sworn that `sizeof(long)` is 4 with gcc on a 32 bit platform.

Comment: @stusmith: Linux uses ILP32 and LP64, which means that an `int` is *always* 32 bit, a `long long` is *always* 64 bit (although I believe there were some discussions about moving to 128 bit for DEC Alpha CPUs) and a `long` is always the same as a pointer. So, if you're running on 32 bit Linux, then your Haskell ints are indeed twice the size.

Comment: `long` is not 64-bit on any 32-bit Linux-based target.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For testing purpose I have just set `searchTo = 100000`. The time taken is **7.34s**. A few modification leads to some big improvement:

1. Use an `Integer` instead of `Int64`. This improves the time to **1.75s**.
2. Use an accumulator (you don't need sequenceLength to be lazy right?) **1.54s**.

   ```hs
   seqLen2 :: Int -> Integer -> Int
   seqLen2 a 1 = a
   seqLen2 a n = seqLen2 (a+1) (nextNumber n)

   sequenceLength :: Integer -> Int
   sequenceLength = seqLen2 1
   ```
3. Rewrite the `nextNumber` using `quotRem`, thus avoiding computing the division twice (once in `even` and once in `div`). **1.27s**.

   ```hs
   nextNumber :: Integer -> Integer
   nextNumber n 
       | r == 0    = q
       | otherwise = 6*q + 4
       where (q,r) = quotRem n 2
   ```
4. Use [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) instead of `maximumBy`. The problem of `maximumBy . comparing` is that the `sequenceLength` function is called more than once for each value. **0.32s**.

   ```hs
   longestSequence = snd $ maximum [(sequenceLength a, a) | a <- [1..searchTo]]
   ```

---

Note:

- I check the time by compiling with `ghc -O` and run with `+RTS -s`)
- My machine is running on Mac OS X 10.6. The GHC version is 6.12.2. The compiled file is in i386 architecture.)
- The C problem runs at **0.078s** with the corresponding parameter. It is compiled with `gcc -O3 -m32`.

Comment: OK that's really interesting. I assumed (mistakenly obviously) that the arbitrary-sized Integer type would be slower than a 64-bit Int64 type. Also, I assumed tail-call recursion would be optimized to a loop. Do you have any links for these sorts of hints?

Comment: @stusmith: `1 + (sequenceLength next)` is not really tail recursive because `sequenceLength` is not at top level. For optimization hints, see http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html

Comment: @stusmith: if you're on a 64-bit OS using Int64 may be faster, but the `Integer` type is very heavily optimized to use word-sized data when possible.  Since that's true most of time in this problem, Integer is the faster choice.

Comment: @stusmith: This is an example, where Lisp-style prefix notation or Forth-style postfix notation is easier to read than mathematical mixfix notation. In Lisp, the last line of `sequenceLength` would be `(+ 1 (sequenceLength next))`, in Forth it would be `next sequenceLength 1 +`. In both cases, it's easy to see that `+` is in the tail position, not `sequenceLength`, ergo the function is *not* tail recursive. You can even see that in Haskell, if you write everything in prefix (aka function) notation: `sequenceLength n = (+) 1 (sequenceLength next)`

Comment: Excellent answer, thankyou. The lack of tail-recursion now seems obvious! It's a real shame that certain functions need to be avoided for good performance (I still can't see why maximumBy needs to call the comparator function more than once per element). It also seems a shame that everything is allocated on the heap - taking your suggestions I get a timing of just over 10s, ie 10x slower than C - and I suspect that's due to Haskell using the heap as opposed to registers.

Comment: @stusmith: The comparator function is called once per pair of argument, but `comparing sequenceLength` as that comparator function calls `sequenceLength` twice. Even worse, the time taken for `sequenceLength` is proportional to its output, and you are finding the maximum...

Answer (score 12):

Although this is already rather old, let me chime in, there's one crucial point that hasn't been addressed before.

First, the timings of the different programmes on my box. Since I'm on a 64-bit linux system, they show somewhat different characteristics: using `Integer` instead of `Int64` does not improve performance as it would with a 32-bit GHC, where each `Int64` operation would incur the cost of a C-call while the computations with `Integer`s fitting in signed 32-bit integers don't need a foreign call (since only few operations exceed that range here, `Integer` is the better choice on a 32-bit GHC).

- C: 0.3 seconds
- Original Haskell: 14.24 seconds, using `Integer` instead of `Int64`: 33.96 seconds
- KennyTM's improved version: 5.55 seconds, using `Int`: 1.85 seconds
- Chris Kuklewicz's version: 5.73 seconds, using `Int`: 1.90 seconds
- FUZxxl's version: 3.56 seconds, using `quotRem` instead of `divMod`: 1.79 seconds

So what have we?

1. Calculate the length with an accumulator so the compiler can transform it (basically) into a loop
2. Don't recalculate the sequence lengths for the comparisons
3. Don't use `div` resp. `divMod` when it's not necessary, `quot` resp. `quotRem` are much faster

What is still missing?

```c
if (j % 2 == 0)
    j = j / 2;
else
    j = 3 * j + 1;
```

Any C compiler I have used transforms the test `j % 2 == 0` into a bit-masking and doesn't use a division instruction. GHC does not (yet) do that. So testing `even n` or computing `` n `quotRem` 2 `` is quite an expensive operation. Replacing `nextNumber` in KennyTM's `Integer` version with

```hs
nextNumber :: Integer -> Integer
nextNumber n
    | fromInteger n .&. 1 == (0 :: Int) = n `quot` 2
    | otherwise = 3*n+1
```

reduces its running time to 3.25 seconds (Note: for `Integer`, `` n `quot` 2 `` is faster than `` n `shiftR` 1 ``, that takes 12.69 seconds!).

Doing the same in the `Int` version reduces its running time to 0.41 seconds. For `Int`s, the bit-shift for division by 2 is a bit faster than the `quot` operation, reducing its running time to 0.39 seconds.

Eliminating the construction of the list (that doesn't appear in the C version either),

```hs
module Main (main) where

import Data.Bits

result :: Int
result = findMax 0 0 1

findMax :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
findMax start len can
    | can > 1000000 = start
    | canlen > len = findMax can canlen (can+1)
    | otherwise = findMax start len (can+1)
      where
        canlen = findLen 1 can

findLen :: Int -> Int -> Int
findLen l 1 = l
findLen l n
    | n .&. 1 == 0  = findLen (l+1) (n `shiftR` 1)
    | otherwise     = findLen (l+1) (3*n+1)

main :: IO ()
main = print result
```

yields a further small speedup, resulting in a running time of 0.37 seconds.

So the Haskell version that's in close correspondence to the C version doesn't take that much longer, it's a factor of ~1.3.

Well, let's be fair, there's an inefficiency in the C version that's not present in the Haskell versions,

```c
if (this_terms > terms)
{
    terms = this_terms;
    longest = i;
}
```

appearing in the inner loop. Lifting that out of the inner loop in the C version reduces its running time to 0.27 seconds, making the factor ~1.4.

Answer (score 5):

The comparing may be recomputing `sequenceLength` too much. This is my best version:

```hs
type I = Integer
data P = P {-# UNPACK #-} !Int {-# UNPACK #-} !I deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)

searchTo = 1000000

nextNumber :: I -> I
nextNumber n = case quotRem n 2 of
                  (n2,0) -> n2
                  _ -> 3*n+1

sequenceLength :: I -> Int
sequenceLength x = count x 1 where
  count 1 acc = acc
  count n acc = count (nextNumber n) (succ acc)

longestSequence = maximum . map (\i -> P (sequenceLength i) i) $ [1..searchTo]

main = putStrLn $ show $ longestSequence
```

The answer and timing are slower than C, but it does use arbitrary precision integers (through the `Integer` type):

```
ghc -O2 --make euler14-fgij.hs
time ./euler14-fgij
P 525 837799

real 0m3.235s
user 0m3.184s
sys  0m0.015s
```

Answer (score 4):

Haskell's lists are heap-based, whereas your C code is exceedingly tight and makes no heap use at all. You need to refactor to remove the dependency on lists.

Answer (score 4):

Even if I'm a bit late, here is mine, I removed the dependency on lists and this solution uses no heap at all too.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
-- Compiled with ghc -O2 -fvia-C -optc-O3 -Wall euler.hs
module Main (main) where

searchTo :: Int
searchTo = 1000000

nextNumber :: Int -> Int
nextNumber n = case n `divMod` 2 of
   (k,0) -> k
   _     -> 3*n + 1

sequenceLength :: Int -> Int
sequenceLength n = sl 1 n where
  sl k 1 = k
  sl k x = sl (k + 1) (nextNumber x)

longestSequence :: Int
longestSequence = testValues 1 0 0 where
  testValues number !longest !longestNum
    | number > searchTo     = longestNum
    | otherwise            = testValues (number + 1) longest' longestNum' where
    nlength  = sequenceLength number
    (longest',longestNum') = if nlength > longest
      then (nlength,number)
      else (longest,longestNum)

main :: IO ()
main = print longestSequence
```

I compiled this piece with `ghc -O2 -fvia-C -optc-O3 -Wall euler.hs` and it runs in 5 secs, compared to 80 of the beginning implementation. It doesn't uses `Integer`, but because I'm on a 64-bit machine, the results may be cheated.

The compiler can unbox all `Int`s in this case, resulting in really fast code. It runs faster than all other solutions I've seen so far, but C is still faster.