# What performance can I expect from Int32 and Int64?

Tags: haskell, 64-bit, int, 32bit-64bit, word-size

I often see pprograms like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646330/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-this-haskell-program), where `Int64` is an absolute performance killer on 32-bit platforms. My question is now:

If I need a specific word length for my task (in my case a RNG), is `Int64` efficient on 64-bit platforms or will it still use the C-calls? And how efficient is converting an `Int64` to an `Int`?

Comment: I would recommend using `Integer` as a first try.

Comment: I need a fixed word size for implementing Xorshift, so Integer is no choice.

Comment: I would use whichever of `Int32` and `Int64` is better-suited for your RNG algorithm.  Create a type synonym so you can easily test it later.  Also be aware that an `Int` isn't the same as `Int32` (the Haskell spec only guarantees that an `Int` is at least 31 bits).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841577/performance-problem-with-euler-problem-and-recursion-on-int64-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on a 64bit system Int64 *should* be fine, I don't know for sure though.

More importantly if you're doing Crypto or random-number-generation you **MUST** use the data type that the algorithm says to use, also be careful of signed-ness. If you do-not do this you will have the wrong results, which might mean that your cryptography is not secure or your random number generator is not really random (RNGs are hard, and many look random but aren't).

For any other type of work use Integer wherever you can, or even better, make your program polymorphic using the Integral type-class.  Then if you think your program is slower than it should be profile it to determine where you should concentrate when you try to speed it up.  if you use the Integral type-class changing from Integer to Int is easy.  Haskell should be smart enough to specialize (most) code that uses polymorphism to avoid overheads.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting article on 64 bit performance here:

[Isn’t my code going to be faster on 64-bit???](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/04/28/413320.aspx)

As the article states, the big bottleneck isn't the processor, it's the cache and memory I/O.

Comment: First, for my purpose, I just have one single number I want to manipulate, so memory access should be no problem. The real problem is, that GHC is known to do many things over C calls which isn't always clear.

Comment: The question really appears to be Haskell specific.