# Performance problem with Euler problem and recursion on Int64 types

Tags: windows, performance, haskell, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I'm currently learning Haskell using the project Euler problems as my playground.
I was astound by how slow my Haskell programs turned out to be compared to similar
programs written in other languages. I'm wondering if I've forseen something, or if this is the kind of performance penalties one has to expect when using Haskell.

The following program in inspired by Problem 331, but I've changed it before posting so I don't spoil anything for other people. It computes the arc length of a discrete circle drawn on a 2^30 x 2^30 grid. It is a simple tail recursive implementation and I make sure that the updates of the accumulation variable keeping track of the arc length is strict. Yet it takes almost one and a half minute to complete (compiled with the -O flag with ghc).

```
import Data.Int

arcLength :: Int64->Int64
arcLength n = arcLength' 0 (n-1) 0 0 where
    arcLength' x y norm2 acc
        | x > y = acc
        | norm2 < 0 = arcLength' (x + 1) y (norm2 + 2*x +1) acc
        | norm2 > 2*(n-1) = arcLength' (x - 1) (y-1) (norm2 - 2*(x + y) + 2) acc
        | otherwise = arcLength' (x + 1) y (norm2 + 2*x + 1) $! (acc + 1)

main = print $ arcLength (2^30)
```

Here is a corresponding implementation in Java. It takes about 4.5 seconds to complete.

```
public class ArcLength {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    long n = 1 << 30;
    long x = 0;
    long y = n-1;
    long acc = 0;
    long norm2 = 0;
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while(x <= y) {
        if (norm2 < 0) {
            norm2 += 2*x + 1;
            x++;
        } else if (norm2 > 2*(n-1)) {
            norm2 += 2 - 2*(x+y);
            x--;
            y--;
        } else {
            norm2 += 2*x + 1;
            x++;
            acc++;
        }
    }

    time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
    System.err.println(acc);
    System.err.println(time);
}
```

}

EDIT: After the discussions in the comments I made som modifications in the Haskell code and did some performance tests. First I changed n to 2^29 to avoid overflows. Then I tried 6 different version: With Int64 or Int and with bangs before either norm2 or both and norm2 and acc in the declaration `arcLength' x  y !norm2 !acc`. All are compiled with

```
ghc -O3 -prof -rtsopts -fforce-recomp -XBangPatterns arctest.hs
```

Here are the results:

```
(Int !norm2 !acc)
total time  =        3.00 secs   (150 ticks @ 20 ms)
total alloc =       2,892 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

(Int norm2 !acc)
total time  =        3.56 secs   (178 ticks @ 20 ms)
total alloc =       2,892 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

(Int norm2 acc)
total time  =        3.56 secs   (178 ticks @ 20 ms)
total alloc =       2,892 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

(Int64 norm2 acc)
arctest.exe: out of memory

(Int64 norm2 !acc)
total time  =       48.46 secs   (2423 ticks @ 20 ms)
total alloc = 26,246,173,228 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

(Int64 !norm2 !acc)
total time  =       31.46 secs   (1573 ticks @ 20 ms)
total alloc =       3,032 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)
```

I'm using GHC 7.0.2 under a 64-bit Windows 7 (The Haskell platform binary distribution). According to the comments, the problem does not occur when compiling under other configurations. This makes me think that the Int64 type is broken in the Windows release.

Comment: Did you tried a bang pattern? `arcLength' x y !norm2 !acc`? `norm2` and `acc` are not always passed stricly because they might not needed when the first branch is taken. BTW, it takes only 6 secs on my machine.

Comment: Generally, Haskell can be one of the faster languages around. There's propably something in your Haskell code that causes worse complexity or doesn't play nice with GHC's optimizations.

Comment: `-O2` is the typical flag for GHC optimization.  -O doesn't do too much, iirc.

Comment: The comments seem to suggest this is a bug related to GHC 7.0.2 and 64 bit GMP (where the `Int64` type comes from) on 32 bit Windows. Can you either upgrade the `libgmp`, upgrade GHC to 7.0.3 or test on 64 bit Windows?

Comment: I get the same behaviour on GHC 7.0.3. I'm also running on 64 bit Windows. But I suspect that the binary distribution of the Haskell platform is 32-bit. There weren't any 64-downloads.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hm, I installed a fresh Haskell platform with 7.0.3, and get roughly the following core for your program (`-ddump-simpl`):

```
Main.$warcLength' =
  \ (ww_s1my :: GHC.Prim.Int64#) (ww1_s1mC :: GHC.Prim.Int64#)
    (ww2_s1mG :: GHC.Prim.Int64#) (ww3_s1mK :: GHC.Prim.Int64#) ->
    case {__pkg_ccall ghc-prim hs_gtInt64 [...]
           ww_s1my ww1_s1mC GHC.Prim.realWorld#
[...]
```

So GHC has realized that it can unpack your integers, which is good. But this `hs_getInt64` call looks suspiciously like a C call. Looking at the assembler output (`-ddump-asm`), we see stuff like:

```
pushl %eax
movl 76(%esp),%eax
pushl %eax
call _hs_gtInt64
addl $16,%esp
```

So this looks very much like every operation on the `Int64` get turned into a full-blown C call in the backend. Which is *slow*, obviously.

The [source code](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0/src/GHC-IntWord64.html) of `GHC.IntWord64` seems to verify that: In a 32-bit build (like the one currently shipped with the platform), you will have only emulation via the FFI interface.

Comment: That's right. On a 32 bit machine `Int64` is implemented via the C GMP library. It will have some performance overhead. On a 64 bit machine, no such problems.

Comment: I guess that settles it. Thanks! I also guess it isn't enough to have a 64-bit machine if you have Windows, since there is no 64-bit GHC for windows (http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/WindowsGhc).

Comment: And you will get the same degradation using `Integer` instead (which is also implemented as a C call into `libgmp`).

Answer (score 8):

Hmm, this is interesting. So I just compiled both of your programs, and tried them out:

```
% java -version                                                                                          
java version "1.6.0_18"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.8.7) (6b18-1.8.7-2~squeeze1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)
% javac ArcLength.java                                                                                   
% java ArcLength                                                                                         
843298604
6630
```

So **about 6.6 seconds for the Java solution**. Next is ghc with some optimization:

```
% ghc --version                                                                                          
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 6.12.1
% ghc --make -O arc.hs
% time ./arc                                                                                             
843298604
./arc  12.68s user 0.04s system 99% cpu 12.718 total
```

**Just under 13 seconds for ghc -O**

Trying with some further optimization:

```
% ghc --make -O3
% time ./arc                                                                                             [13:16]
843298604
./arc  5.75s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 5.754 total
```

**With further optimization flags, the haskell solution took under 6 seconds**

It would be interesting to know what version compiler you are using.

Comment: Same for me. Things got faster when I changed `Int64` to `Int` and added an explicit type signature to the inner worker. I am on x64, ghc 7.0.3

Comment: I use ghc under windows.
ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.0.2

Comment: dbergh: x86 or x64? Which porcessor speed?

Comment: @FUZxxl Shouldn't the compiler automatically infer that the type of x, y etc. is the same as the type for n? Using Int causes overflow, at least if Int is 32 bit.

Comment: @dbergh: I am on x64, so `Int` is a 64 bit type. About the type-signatures: I had a look at the core representation and was a bit shocked when I saw, that there are still some `Integer`s lurking around. But now I think, that they emerge from somewhere else. If `Int` overflows, why not try `Integer`? ghc builtin `Integer` type is blazing fast, and you don't have to wrry about boundaries.

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E8400 @ 3.00GHz. I also tried it on a slower Linux system (Intel Atom) using ghc -O3 version 6.12.1. With this configuration it takes 5m20s.

Comment: Also non x64 processor feature 64 bit data registers. Int64 turns out to be significantly faster than Integer in this case (I killed the process after 4 minutes using Integer). In any case, this does not explain the huge differences in computation time. @Monk Did you really copy the code without altering it?

Comment: I see the same slowness with Int64 when compiled by 32 bit version of GHC 7.0.2 and the same <5 sec time when compiled with x64 version (7.0.3 though). Btw -fllvm option seems to speed up 32 bit version of this (not sure how it would behave with x64 since it ignores -fllvm in x64 GHC on MacOS)

Comment: I have copied the haskell code posted by @dbergh and it finished in [real    0m4.322s,
user    0m4.320s,
sys     0m0.000s] Edit: also compiled with -O3

Comment: Hmm, when compiled without -O3 I had killed it after a minute or so, so the optimization done by -O3 here is HUGE.

Comment: @dbergh I did indeed just copy the code without altering it. My initial benchmark was run with an x64 binary on an x64 linux box. I also run x64 windows on my desktop, so I just tried your code there. The haskell code indeed runs much much slower, possibly this performance hit is because you can't produce an x64 binary from ghc for windows? Will update my answer in a sec.

Comment: @monk: IIRC no. That might be the issue.

Comment: @Ed'ka: On my platform -fllvm *slowed it down* from 6 secs to 7 secs.

Comment: But no longer. After adding some bangs here and there, llvm made it run at about 5.5 secs, which is quite impressing. For fun, I converted the java code to C. It runs in 2.8 secs when compiled with -O3 on x64 linux.

Comment: Hmmm, I find it kind of disappointing that randomly cluttering the code with exclamaition marks have such a big impact. But to me it seems that the real issue is that the implementation of the 64-bit arithmetic is bad... According to my timings, using 64-bit integers almost increases the execution time by a factor 10.

Comment: @dbergh: don't *randomly clutter*. Pay attention to the evaluation (strict / lazy) and state what behavior you want.

Comment: @Don Stewart. Ok what do you think is good in this case? I found the variable `acc` was obvious in this case. After some thought also  `norm2` seemed to be a good candidate, but I kind of think that compiler should find it on its own. The variables `x`, `y` and `n` I would say definitely not. I actually tried it `!n` slowed things down (although I don't understand why) and the others had no impact.

Comment: Yes, you're right. `acc` isn't tested in the loop, so can be inferred to be lazy. `norm2` may or may not be, based on how you write the loops (see my answer). `ghc -O2` can see the strictness of everything else. This is "demand analysis", and you seem to have a good intuition for it.

Answer (score 7):

There's a couple of interesting things in your question.

You should be using `-O2` primarily. It will just do a better job (in this case, identifying and removing laziness that was still present in the `-O` version).

Secondly, your Haskell isn't quite the same as the Java (it does different tests and branches). As with others, running your code on my Linux box results in around 6s runtime. It seems fine.

**Make sure it is the same as the Java**

One idea: let's do a literal transcription of your Java, with the same control flow, operations and types.

```
import Data.Bits
import Data.Int

loop :: Int -> Int
loop n = go 0 (n-1) 0 0
    where
        go :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
        go x y acc norm2
            | x <= y        = case () of { _
                | norm2 < 0         -> go (x+1) y     acc     (norm2 + 2*x + 1)
                | norm2 > 2 * (n-1) -> go (x-1) (y-1) acc     (norm2 + 2 - 2 * (x+y))
                | otherwise         -> go (x+1) y     (acc+1) (norm2 + 2*x + 1)
            }
            | otherwise     = acc

main = print $ loop (1 `shiftL` 30)
```

**Peek at the core**

We'll take a quick peek at the Core, [using `ghc-core`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-core), and it shows a very nice loop of unboxed type:

```
main_$s$wgo
  :: Int#
     -> Int#
     -> Int#
     -> Int#
     -> Int#

main_$s$wgo =
  \ (sc_sQa :: Int#)
    (sc1_sQb :: Int#)
    (sc2_sQc :: Int#)
    (sc3_sQd :: Int#) ->
    case <=# sc3_sQd sc2_sQc of _ {
      False -> sc1_sQb;
      True ->
        case <# sc_sQa 0 of _ {
          False ->
            case ># sc_sQa 2147483646 of _ {
              False ->
                main_$s$wgo
                  (+# (+# sc_sQa (*# 2 sc3_sQd)) 1)
                  (+# sc1_sQb 1)
                  sc2_sQc
                      (+# sc3_sQd 1);
              True ->
                main_$s$wgo
                  (-#
                     (+# sc_sQa 2)
                     (*# 2 (+# sc3_sQd sc2_sQc)))
                  sc1_sQb
                  (-# sc2_sQc 1)
                  (-# sc3_sQd 1)
            };
          True ->
            main_$s$wgo
              (+# (+# sc_sQa (*# 2 sc3_sQd)) 1)
              sc1_sQb
              sc2_sQc
              (+# sc3_sQd 1)
```

that is, all unboxed into registers. **That loop looks great!**

And performs just fine (Linux/x86-64/GHC 7.03):

```
./A  5.95s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 5.980 total
```

**Checking the asm**

We get reasonable assembly too, as a nice loop:

```
Main_mainzuzdszdwgo_info:
        cmpq    %rdi, %r8
        jg      .L8
.L3:
        testq   %r14, %r14
        movq    %r14, %rdx
        js      .L4
        cmpq    $2147483646, %r14
        jle     .L9
.L5:
        leaq    (%rdi,%r8), %r10
        addq    $2, %rdx
        leaq    -1(%rdi), %rdi
        addq    %r10, %r10
        movq    %rdx, %r14
        leaq    -1(%r8), %r8
        subq    %r10, %r14
        jmp     Main_mainzuzdszdwgo_info
.L9:
        leaq    1(%r14,%r8,2), %r14
        addq    $1, %rsi
        leaq    1(%r8), %r8
        jmp     Main_mainzuzdszdwgo_info
.L8:
        movq    %rsi, %rbx
        jmp     *0(%rbp)
.L4:
        leaq    1(%r14,%r8,2), %r14
        leaq    1(%r8), %r8
        jmp     Main_mainzuzdszdwgo_info
```

Using the `-fvia-C` backend.

So this looks fine!

---

My suspicion, as mentioned in the comment above, is something to do with the version of `libgmp` you have on 32 bit Windows generating poor code for 64 bit ints. First try upgrading to GHC 7.0.3, and then try some of the other code generator backends, then if you still have an issue with `Int64`, file a bug report to GHC trac.

Broadly confirming that it is indeed the cost of making those C calls in the 32 bit emulation of 64 bit ints, we can replace `Int64` with `Integer`, which is implemented with C calls to GMP on every machine, and indeed, runtime goes from 3s to well over a minute.

*Lesson:* use hardware 64 bits if at all possible.

Comment: Not always possible. Haskell can't compile to 64bit code under windows, so this is not always an option.

Comment: How do you get such clean core output?

Comment: Using `ghc-core`, which you can get here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-core

Answer (score 4):

The normal optimization flag for performance concerned code is `-O2`.  What you used, `-O`, does very little.  `-O3` doesn't do much (any?) more than `-O2` - it even used to include experimental "optimizations" that often made programs notably slower.

With -O2 I get performance competitive with Java:

```
tommd@Mavlo:Test$ uname -r -m
2.6.37 x86_64
tommd@Mavlo:Test$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.0.3

tommd@Mavlo:Test$ ghc -O2 so.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( so.hs, so.o )
Linking so ...
tommd@Mavlo:Test$ time ./so
843298604

real    0m4.948s
user    0m4.896s
sys     0m0.000s
```

And Java is about 1 second faster (20%):

```
tommd@Mavlo:Test$ time java ArcLength
843298604
3880

real    0m3.961s
user    0m3.936s
sys     0m0.024s
```

But an interesting thing about GHC is it has many different backends.  By default it uses the native code generator (NCG), which we timed above.  There's also an LLVM backend that often does better... but not here:

```
tommd@Mavlo:Test$ ghc -O2 so.hs -fllvm -fforce-recomp
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( so.hs, so.o )
Linking so ...
tommd@Mavlo:Test$ time ./so
843298604

real    0m5.973s
user    0m5.968s
sys     0m0.000s
```

But, as FUZxxl mentioned in the comments, LLVM does much better when you add a few strictness annotations:

```
$ ghc -O2 -fllvm -fforce-recomp so.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( so.hs, so.o )
Linking so ...
tommd@Mavlo:Test$ time ./so
843298604

real    0m4.099s
user    0m4.088s
sys     0m0.000s
```

There's also an old "via-c" generator that uses C as an intermediate language.  It does well in this case:

```
tommd@Mavlo:Test$ ghc -O2 so.hs -fvia-c -fforce-recomp
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( so.hs, so.o )

on the commandline:
    Warning: The -fvia-c flag will be removed in a future GHC release
Linking so ...
ttommd@Mavlo:Test$ ti
tommd@Mavlo:Test$ time ./so
843298604

real    0m3.982s
user    0m3.972s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Hopefully the NCG will be improved to match via-c for this case before they remove this backend.

Comment: When you add a bang patterns at the parameter `norm2` in `arcLength'`, the llvm backend does a much better job, because `norm2` is not strict by default.

Comment: Ah! And you have to add a bang at `arcLength !n`, too.

Answer (score 2):

`dberg`, I feel like all of this got off to a bad start with the unfortunate `-O` flag. Just to emphasize a point made by others, for run-of-the-mill compilation and testing, do like me and paste this into your `.bashrc` or whatever:

```
alias ggg="ghc --make -O2"
alias gggg="echo 'Glorious Glasgow for Great Good!' && ghc --make -O2 --fforce-recomp"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've played with the code a little and this version seems to run faster than Java version on my laptop (3.55s vs 4.63s):

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

arcLength :: Int->Int
arcLength n = arcLength' 0 (n-1) 0 0 where
    arcLength' :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
    arcLength' !x !y !norm2 !acc
        | x > y = acc
        | norm2 > 2*(n-1) = arcLength' (x - 1) (y - 1) (norm2 - 2*(x + y) + 2) acc
        | norm2 < 0 = arcLength' (succ x) y (norm2 + x*2 + 1) acc
        | otherwise = arcLength' (succ x) y (norm2 + 2*x + 1) (acc + 1)      

main = print $ arcLength (2^30)
```

:

```
$ ghc -O2 tmp1.hs -fforce-recomp
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( tmp1.hs, tmp1.o )
Linking tmp1 ...

$ time ./tmp1
843298604

real    0m3.553s
user    0m3.539s
sys 0m0.006s
```

Comment: I compiled the Java version with gcj on my machine and it run in 3.5 secs as opposed to haskell, which runs in 6 secs. The JVM makes the code slower.

Comment: @FUZxxl I can't try gcj, but c++ (gcc -O3) version runs here in 2.1s ( vs my ghc's 3.5s - not that bad). Not sure why you're getting 6s with my version, nor can I explain why changing `x+1` to `succ x` makes such a big difference here (5.3s vs 3.6).

Comment: Me too. Mybe my machine is less powerful. On my machine, I got about 2.8 secs for plain C, and 3.5 secs for Java.