# Haskell: return the "list" result of a function as a "list of lists" without using an empty list "[]:foo"

Tags: list, haskell, syntax

What would be the syntax (if possible at all) for returning the list of lists ([[a]]) but without the use of empty list ([]:[a])?
(similar as the second commented guard (2) below, which is incorrect)

This is a function that works correctly:

```
-- Split string on every (shouldSplit == true)
splitWith :: (Char -> Bool) -> [Char] -> [[Char]]
splitWith shouldSplit list = filter (not.null) -- would like to get rid of filter
  (imp' shouldSplit list)
  where 
    imp' _ [] = [[]]
    imp' shouldSplit (x:xs)
      | shouldSplit x  = []:imp' shouldSplit xs  -- (1) this line is adding empty lists
--      | shouldSplit x  = [imp' shouldSplit xs]   -- (2) if this would be correct, no filter needed
      | otherwise  = let (z:zs) = imp' shouldSplit xs in (x:z):zs
```

This is the correct result

```
Prelude> splitWith (== 'a') "miraaaakojajeja234"
["mir","koj","jej","234"]
```

However, it must use "filter" to clean up its result, so I would like to get rid of function "filter".
This is the result without the use of filter:

```
["mir","","","","koj","jej","234"]
```

If "**| shouldSplit x  = imp' shouldSplit xs**" is used instead the first guard, the result is incorrect:

```
["mirkojjej234"]
```

The first guard (1) adds empty list so (I assume) compiler can treat the result as a list of lists ([[a]]).

(I'm not interested in another/different solutions of the function, just the syntax clarification.)

```
.
.
.
```

**ANSWER**:

Answer from Dave4420 led me to the answer, but it was a comment, not an answer so I can't accept it as answer. The solution of the problem was that I'm asking the wrong question. It is not the problem of syntax, but of my algorithm.

There are several answers with another/different solutions that solve the empty list problem, but they are not the answer to my question. However, they expanded my view of ways on how things can be done with basic Haskell syntax, and I thank them for it.

**Edit:**

```
splitWith :: (Char -> Bool) -> String -> [String]
splitWith p = go False
  where 
    go _ [] = [[]]
    go lastEmpty (x:xs)
      | p x        = if lastEmpty then go True xs else []:go True xs
      | otherwise  = let (z:zs) = go False xs in (x:z):zs
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that, but if I use (2), the compiler complains with Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]
Expected type: [a0]
  Actual type: [[a0]]
In the return type of a call of imp'
In the expression: imp' shouldSplit xs EDIT: Seems I deleted the original comment. It was about using one-element list [a]

Comment: You seem to think this is a matter of finding the right syntax, but it is a consequence of your algorithm: when the parameter has 4 `a`s in a row, you will naturally get 3 empty lists in the result.

Comment: Both `imp' shouldSplit xs` and `[]:imp' shouldSplit xs` are of the correct type `[[Char]]`. They both don't work. `[imp' shouldSplit xs]`would be of type `[[[Char]]]` which is of course incorrect and cannot work either. There is no magic syntax to convert `imp' shouldSplit xs` into a value that works without `filter`, without also changing other parts of the algorithm.

Comment: @dave4420: You made me think, so I replaced `[]` with `['x']` and realized that empty list in guard is added as last element on closing the last word, and others are just a consequence of not having any elements. I realize now it is not the matter of syntax, but the algorithm. Thanks!

Comment: @n.m.: What do you mean by `[]:imp' shouldSplit xs` don't work? This one works and produces correct result.

Comment: I mean it doesn't work without `filter`.

Comment: @n.m.: Yes, you're right. I see your point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one utilizes pattern matching to complete the task of not producing empty interleaving lists in a single traversal:

```
splitWith :: Eq a => (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitWith f list = case splitWith' f list of
  []:result -> result
  result -> result
  where
    splitWith' _ [] = []
    splitWith' f (a:[]) = if f a then [] else [[a]]
    splitWith' f (a:b:tail) =
      let next = splitWith' f (b : tail)
      in if f a
        then if a == b
          then next
          else [] : next
        else case next of
          [] -> [[a]]
          nextHead:nextTail -> (a : nextHead) : nextTail
```

Running it:

```
main = do
  print $ splitWith (== 'a') "miraaaakojajeja234"
  print $ splitWith (== 'a') "mirrraaaakkkojjjajeja234"
  print $ splitWith (== 'a') "aaabbbaaa"
```

Produces:

```
["mir","koj","jej","234"]
["mirrr","kkkojjj","jej","234"]
["bbb"]
```

Comment: Nice and basic solution. However, there is a tiny error in guard condition `a == b`. Should be `f a && a == b`, otherwise consecutive elements are lost. If you try `"mirrraaaakkkojjjajeja234"`, you lose r's, k's and j's

Comment: @VlatkoB You're right. I've updated the solution, but a bit differently to avoid repeated conditions.

Comment: I should have paid more attention on the param string and choose better. That "mirrr....." stuff does seem weird.

Comment: I didn't specify all the requirements of my function (it is from "RealWorldHaskell"), so you couldn't know, but this code is not correct. For `splitWith (=='a') "aaabbbaaa"` it produces `["","bbba"]`, while the correct result should be `["bbb"]`. Just in case someone would be reading this as a solution to the RWH problem.

Comment: Yes, it does works correctly for all the values I'm testing with. Though, don't get me wrong, but this is not the best looking code I've seen. ;-)) However, quite a few constructs glued together that look very interesting to a newbie (me).

Comment: @VlatkoB Yes, the solution is quite verbose, but it should be one of the fastest, since it's based on a single traversal, i.e. has complexity `O(n)`.

Comment: Yes, it is the fastest. I made some timings (with `show (length result)`) and the results are surprising. I merged 3 x full HTML of "Chapter 4. Functional programming", about `750KB with 58K "words"`.     Results:    Prelude.words = **0.052** sec, adapted Prelude.words for any character = **0.212** sec, Nikita = **0.796** sec, Chris = **0.856** sec, VlatkoB = **0.960** sec, and (very surprising) Groovy = **685.675** sec. I think Groovy's `++` probably took so much time. Very interesting that so big differences can be made with a little change (Prelude is faster than light).

Comment: @VlatkoB For precise benchmarking your best bet is Criterion library. I've recently published here [an answer with a link to source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15319373/485115) showing how it can be used.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is quite naturally expressed as a fold over the list you're splitting. You need to keep track of two pieces of state - the result list, and the current word that is being built up to append to the result list.

I'd probably write a naive version something like this:

```
splitWith p xs = word:result
    where
        (result, word)        = foldr func ([], []) xs
        func x (result, word) = if p x
            then (word:result,[])
            else (result, x:word)
```

Note that this also leaves in the empty lists, because it appends the current word to the result whenever it detects a new element that satisfies the predicate `p`.

To fix that, just replace the list cons operator `(:)` with a new operator

```
(~:) :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
```

that only conses one list to another if the original list is non-empty. The rest of the algorithm is unchanged.

```
splitWith p xs = word ~: result
    where
        (result, word)        = foldr func ([], []) xs
        func x (result, word) = if p x
            then (word ~: result, [])
            else (result, x:word)
        x ~: xs = if null x then xs else x:xs
```

which does what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I said, I'm not interested in other solutions (the solution in the question works as expected, I just wanted to make it "simpler"). Just wanted to learn why isn't it possible to do it "my way" :-). I'm still learning the basics and I'm trying not to use any Prelude helpers, if possible. However, your solution looks quite simple and interesting, so I'll take a closer look at it.

Comment: Ah, sorry - I managed to read your entire question except for the last line!

Comment: Please see my comment for Nikita. Also not correct for RWH problem. This function produces `["","bbb"]`

Comment: For `splitWith (=='a') "aaabbbaaa"` it produces `["","bbb"]`, so there is still an empty list.

Comment: `:~` operator is causing "Invalid type signature", so maybe `~:~` could be used.

Comment: @VlatkoB Gah. I'd written `~:` originally, and somehow changed it when I came to type it up on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I had a similar idea to Chris, I think, even if not as elegant:

```
splitWith shouldSplit list = imp' list [] []
  where 
    imp' [] accum result = result ++ if null accum then [] else [accum]
    imp' (x:xs) accum result
      | shouldSplit x  = 
          imp' xs [] (result ++ if null accum 
                                   then [] 
                                   else [accum])
      | otherwise  = imp' xs (accum ++ [x]) result
```

Comment: At the moment I like your best because it doesn't

Comment: @VlatkoB Thank you for your comment, but I don't understand...why do you like it?

Comment: An inner implementation, `imp’`, is often called `go`. You don't need to pass `shouldSplit` to the inner function because it never changes, and is in scope from the outer function.

Comment: @pat that is true..I tried to keep it as close to his original as possible

Comment: @groovy: Seems my comment was cut off. I meant because Chris's solution uses explicit fold, and yours does not. I find such solutions more interesting now because I'm trying to wrap my mind around functional way of solving problems and I think (hope) the best way to achieve that is by using only the basic syntax, without helper functions (unless I write them myself). Saying that, I assume in some time I'll like Chris's solution better, as I move on. :-)

Comment: @VlatkoB cool. Take a look at the updated version based on pat's comment

Comment: @groovy: I did and already changed my local version. :-) However, for `splitWith (=='a') "aaabbbaaa"` your code produces `["bbb",""]`, so there is still an empty list.

Comment: @groovy: Works like a charm, for all my tests.

Comment: @pat: Where did you find that inner functions should be called `go`? So far, I've mostly seen `imp` and `imp'`, or a certain name.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844653/haskell-why-the-convention-to-name-a-helper-function-go)

Answer (score 1):

This is basically just an alternating application of `dropWhile` and `break`, isn't it:

```hs
splitWith p xs = g xs
   where
     g xs = let (a,b) = break p (dropWhile p xs)
            in if null a then [] else a : g b
```

You say you aren't interested in other solutions than yours, but other readers might be. It sure is short and seems clear. As you learn, using basic `Prelude` functions becomes second nature. :)

As to your code, a little bit reworked in non-essential ways (using short suggestive function names, like `p` for *"predicate"* and `g` for a main worker function), it is

```hs
splitWith :: (Char -> Bool) -> [Char] -> [[Char]]
splitWith p list = filter (not.null) (g list)
  where 
    g  [] = [[]]
    g (x:xs)
      | p x  = [] : g xs  
      | otherwise  = let (z:zs) = g xs 
                     in (x:z):zs
```

Also, there's no need to pass the predicate as an argument to the worker (as was also mentioned in the comments). Now it is arguably a bit more readable.

Next, with a minimal change it becomes

```hs
splitWith :: (Char -> Bool) -> [Char] -> [[Char]]
splitWith p list = case g list of ([]:r)-> r; x->x
  where 
    g  [] = [[]]
    g (x:xs)
      | p x  = case z of []-> r;    -- start a new word IF not already
                         _ -> []:r  
      | otherwise  = (x:z):zs
           where                    -- now z,zs are accessible
             r@(z:zs) = g xs        -- in both cases
```

which works as you wanted. The top-level `case` is removing at most one empty word here, which serves as a separator marker at some point during the inner function's work. Your `filter (not.null)` is essentially fused into the worker function `g` here, with the *conditional* opening<sup>1</sup> of a new word (i.e. addition<sup>1</sup> of an empty list).

Replacing your `let` with `where` allowed for the variables (`z` etc.) to became accessible in both branches of the second clause of the `g` definition.

In the end, your algorithm was close enough, and the code could be fixed after all.

---

<sup>1</sup> when thinking "right-to-left". In reality the list is constructed left-to-right, in guarded recursion ⁄ [tail recursion modulo cons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons) fashion.