# Calling and Passing Nested Functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, callback, nested-function

I have a function that returns the LCM of a range of numbers. It works great, but this has a function inside of a function inside of a function. My question is why can I not simplify the nested smallestCommon() by removing scm() from inside of it? Why does this particular solution need this if else functionality so deeply nested?

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  var max = Math.max(...arr);
  var min = Math.min(...arr);
  var candidate = max;

  var smallestCommon = function(low, high) {
  // inner function to use 'high' variable
    function scm(l, h) {
      if (h % l === 0) {
         return h;
      } else {
        return scm(l, h + high);
      }
    }
    return scm(low, high);
  };

  for (var i = min; i <= max; i += 1) {
    candidate = smallestCommon(i, candidate);
  }

  return candidate;
}

smallestCommons([5, 1]); // should return 60
smallestCommons([1, 13]); // should return 360360
smallestCommons([23, 18]); //should return 6056820
```

Comment: Does LCM = lowest common multiple? If so, it's not clear why the LCM of `[5, 1]` is `60`.

Comment: (LCM = Least Common Multiple) The LCM of 5 and 1 is 5. The LCM of 1 and 13 is 13. The LCM of 23 and 18 is 414. I'm a little confused as what you're after. There is no need to nest the declarations of these functions. They will run faster if you extract the `scm` function and just call it inside of `smallestCommons`. The `smallestCommon` function is completely extraneous considering all it does is define `scm` and return an invocation of `scm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having inner functions isn't necessarily bad. Sometimes you want to reduce some local duplication, but don't want to also create a new top-level function. Used carefully, they can clean up code.

In your particular case though, it isn't necessary to have it nested. You can just pass in the `high` variable as a third parameter:

```
function scm(l, h, high) {
  if (h % l === 0) {
     return h;
  } else {
    return scm(l, h + high, high);
  }
}

function smallestCommon (low, high) {
  return scm(low, high, high);
}
```

This is actually a fairly common pattern when dealing with recursion: have a recursive function, and a helper function that simplifies calling the recursive function. In functional languages where recursion is common though, [it's actually commonplace to have a local recursive function like you had originally (often called something like `go`).](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5844850/3000206)

---

And it's a shame that [JS doesn't have a `range` function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3895478/3000206). `smallestCommons` is basically just a reduction over the range `[min,max]`. Between the lack of `range` function and `smallestCommon` having it's arguments in the wrong order though, converting your code to use `reduce` unfortunately got a little bulky:

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  var max = Math.max(...arr);
  var min = Math.min(...arr);

  return Array.from(new Array(max - min), (x,i) => i + min)
              .reduce((acc, i) => smallestCommon(i, acc), max);
}
```

Comment: Great explanation and I completely agree with your assessment of this use case.

Comment: Nice answer. We approach the problem similarly :D

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest breaking this down into smaller parts. Instead of one function that's complicated and difficult to debug, you'll have lots of functions that are easy to write and debug. Smaller functions are easier to test and reuse in other parts of your program too -

```js
const gcd = (m, n) =>
  n === 0
    ? m
    : gcd (n, m % n)

const lcm = (m, n) =>
  Math.abs (m * n) / gcd (m, n)
  
console.log
  ( lcm (1, 5)    // 5
  , lcm (3, 4)    // 12
  , lcm (23, 18)  // 414
  )
```

Now we have `minmax`. Unique to this implementation is that it finds the min and the max using only a *single* traversal of the input array -

```js
const None =
  Symbol ()

const list = (...values) =>
  values

const minmax = ([ x = None, ...rest ], then = list) =>
  x === None
    ? then (Infinity, -Infinity)
    : minmax
        ( rest
        , (min, max) =>
            then
              ( Math.min (min, x)
              , Math.max (max, x)
              )
        )

console.log
  ( minmax ([ 3, 4, 2, 5, 1 ])    // [ 1, 5 ]
  , minmax ([ 1, 5 ])             // [ 1, 5 ]
  , minmax ([ 5, 1 ])             // [ 1, 5 ]
  , minmax ([ 9 ])                // [ 9, 9 ]
  , minmax ([])                   // [ Infinity, -Infinity ]
  )
```

By default `minmax` returns a `list` of the min and max values. We can plug the min and max directly into a `range` function, which might be more useful to us, as we'll see later -

```js
const range = (m, n) =>
  m > n
    ? []
    : [ m, ... range (m + 1, n ) ]

console.log
  ( minmax ([ 3, 4, 2, 5, 1 ], range)    // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
  , minmax ([ 1, 5 ], range)             // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
  , minmax ([ 5, 1 ], range)             // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
  , minmax ([ 9 ], range)                // [ 9 ]
  , minmax ([], range)                   // []
  )
```

Now that we can find the min and max of the input, create a range between the two, all that's left is calculating the `lcm` of the values in the range. Taking many values and reducing them to a single value is done with [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) -

```
console.log
  ( minmax ([1, 5], range) .reduce (lcm, 1) // 60
  , minmax ([5, 1], range) .reduce (lcm, 1) // 60
  )
```

Wrap that up in a function and we're done -

```js
const smallestCommons = xs =>
  minmax (xs, range) .reduce (lcm, 1)

console.log
  ( smallestCommons ([ 5, 1 ])    // 60
  , smallestCommons ([ 1, 13 ])   // 360360
  , smallestCommons ([ 23, 18 ])  // 6056820
  )
```

Verify the result in your own browser below -

```js
const gcd = (m, n) =>
  n === 0
    ? m
    : gcd (n, m % n)

const lcm = (m, n) =>
  Math.abs (m * n) / gcd (m, n)

const None =
  Symbol ()

const list = (...values) =>
  values

const minmax = ([ x = None, ...xs ], then = list) =>
  x === None
    ? then (Infinity, -Infinity)
    : minmax
        ( xs
        , (min, max) =>
            then
              ( Math.min (min, x)
              , Math.max (max, x)
              )
        )

const range = (m, n) =>
  m > n
    ? []
    : [ m, ... range (m + 1, n ) ]

const smallestCommons = xs =>
  minmax (xs, range) .reduce (lcm, 1)

console.log
  ( smallestCommons ([ 5, 1 ])    // 60
  , smallestCommons ([ 1, 13 ])   // 360360
  , smallestCommons ([ 23, 18 ])  // 6056820
  )
```

---

**extra**

Above, `minmax` is defined using continuation passing style. We save extra computation by passing `range` as the specified continuation (`then`). However, we can call `minmax` without specifying a continuation and spread (`...`) the intermediate value to `range`. Either program might make more sense to you. The result is the same -

```
const smallestCommons = xs =>
  range (...minmax (xs)) .reduce (lcm, 1)

console.log
  ( smallestCommons ([ 5, 1 ])    // 60
  , smallestCommons ([ 1, 13 ])   // 360360
  , smallestCommons ([ 23, 18 ])  // 6056820
  )
```

---

**same pig, different farm**

> `smallestCommons` is basically just a reduction over the range `[min,max]` - [@Carcigenicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53324720/633183)

Hopefully it helps to see the same result from multiple approaches :D

---

**sourface**

Some people will despise the above implementation of `minmax` regardless of its elegance and flexibility. Now that we maybe understand reducing a little better, we can show how `minmax` might be better implemented using direct style -

```
const minmax = xs =>
  xs .reduce
    ( ([ min, max ], x) =>
        [ Math.min (min, x)
        , Math.max (max, x)
        ]
    , [ Infinity, -Infinity ]
    )

const smallestCommons = xs =>
  range (...minmax (xs)) .reduce (lcm, 1) // direct style now required here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unnest it, if you rewrite the inner functions in such a way, that they don't reference variables in their outer scope.

```
function scm(l, h, step) {
  if (h % l === 0) {
     return h;
  } else {
    return scm(l, h + h, step);
  }
}

function smallestCommons(arr) {
  var max = Math.max(...arr);
  var min = Math.min(...arr);
  return scm(min, max, max);
}
```

It might blow your stack though, but that's a different problem. If you get a `RangeError`, you have to rewrite `scm` to be loop based instead of recursive.