# Reachable nodes in a graph

Tags: haskell, graph

I want to check from which nodes a node is reachable.

So I want to give a graph and node and return a list of all nodes where I can reach the graph from. (I know there is Data.Graph, but I want to try to understand it from scratch, and don't use it on purpose.

To build up the graph I got the following Data.

```hs
data Node = Node String [Node]
```

The String is just a representation of a name the node has.

[image: Example]

Which is the representaion of the graph.

```hs
node1 = Node "node1" [node2,node3]
node2 = Node "node2" [node3]
node3 = Node "node3" [node4,node5]
node4 = Node "node4" [node1,node2]
node5 = Node "node5" [node4]
```

Also I got the (directly) reaching Nodes in:

```hs
canReachNext (Node x y) = y
```

Now my basic idea was this:

```hs
listForReachables:: Node n => n -> [n]
listForReachables x
    | contains[x] (canReachNext x) == False = listForReachables (head(canReachNext (x)))
    | contains [x] (canReachNext x)== True = [x]
    | otherwise = []
```

This ends in an endless Loop if I run

```hs
listForReachables node1
```

I get the reason why it ends in a loop. Because in this example the head will always have an other  list.

My problem and where I am stuck is, that im used to the OOP and in this case it feels like I need a list to remember which nodes I've checked, and which nodes I still have to check.

Comment: That is not a good data representation to solve that problem in Haskell.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Why not? Obviously an adjacency map is popular because it's easier to build, but if you can build a given graph using this representation it seems perfectly possible to run graph algorithms on it.

Comment: @amalloy I didn't say it was impossible, just that it wasn't good. The main thing I don't like is that it fails "make illegal states unrepresentable" since you could have a graph with two nodes with the same label. To me, this data structure seems like it's meant for a language that has reference equality, which Haskell doesn't*.

Comment: * yeah yeah `reallyUnsafePtrEquality#`..., but please don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Haskell, it is common for one function with the desired type to call another one with many parameters. You can use these to capture the intermediate state.

In this case, I added a list of nodes already visited. The first parameter is a list of nodes to explore. When the program encounters a node that has already passed, it discards it and continues with other nodes from the first parameter.

Your exit condition can't occur because the `Bool` has only the `True` and the `False` values. These no longer need to be compared.

I had a problem that the standard classes `Show` and `Eq` hung when applied to `node1`, so I made an incomplete `contains` and `name` for myself.

If you have a problem with cycling, be sure to check that `show node1` and `contains` are fine. Alternatively, make a non-cyclic test chart.

```
node6 = Node "node6" [node7]
node7 = Node "node7" []
```

Code:

```
data Node = Node String [Node]

node1 = Node "node1" [node2,node3]
node2 = Node "node2" [node3]
node3 = Node "node3" [node4,node5]
node4 = Node "node4" [node1,node2]
node5 = Node "node5" [node4]

canReachNext :: Node -> [Node]
canReachNext (Node x y) = y

name :: Node -> String
name (Node x y) = x

contains :: [Node] -> [Node] -> Bool
contains (x:xs) ys = any ((\(Node a b) -> \(Node c d) ->  a == c) x) ys

listForReachables :: Node -> [Node]
listForReachables x = listForReachables' (x:[]) []

listForReachables' :: [Node] -> [Node] -> [Node]
listForReachables' (x:xs) ys
    | contains [x] ys  = listForReachables' xs ys
    | otherwise = listForReachables' (xs ++ canReachNext x) (x:ys)
listForReachables' [] ys = ys
```

Test:

```
map name $ listForReachables node1
```

Output:

```
["node5","node4","node3","node2","node1"]
```

Note 1.: [There is convention to name a helper function "go"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844653/haskell-why-the-convention-to-name-a-helper-function-go).

```
listForReachables :: Node -> [Node]
listForReachables x = go (x:[]) [] where
 go (x:xs) ys
    | contains [x] ys  = go xs ys
    | otherwise = go (xs ++ canReachNext x) (x:ys)
 go [] ys = ys
```

Answer (score 1):

> it feels like I need a list to remember which nodes I've checked, and which nodes I still have to check.

I agree. So let's use one!

```
listForReachables :: Node -> [String] -> ([String], [Node])
listForReachables node@(Node src tgts) visited
    | src `elem` visited = (visited, [])
    | otherwise = loopOver tgts (src:visited)
    where
    loopOver [] visited = (visited, [node])
    loopOver (tgt:tgts) visited = let
        (visited', reachables) = listForReachables tgt visited'
        (visited'', reachables') = loopOver tgts visited'
        in (visited'', reachables ++ reachables')
```

Actually, an experienced Haskeller would notice this pattern:

```
(visited', reachables) = listForReachables tgt visited'
(visited'', reachables') = loopOver tgts visited'
```

and realize that this was exactly the implementation of `(>>=)` for the `State [String]` monad. So they would probably change the implementation this way:

```
listForReachables :: Node -> State [String] [Node]
listForReachables node@(Node src tgts) = do
    done <- gets (src `elem`)
    if done then pure [] else do
        modify (src:)
        reachables <- mapM listForReachables tgts
        pure (node : concat reachables)
```

Pretty compact! Let's try it:

```
> name (Node nm _) = nm
> map name (evalState (listForReachables node1) [])
["node1","node2","node3","node4","node5"]
```