# Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Integer'

Tags: haskell

I have the following Haskell code:

```
-- Problem 69

import ProjectEuler

phi :: Integer -> Integer
phi n = n * product [p - 1 | p <- primeDivisors n] `div` product [p | p <- primeDivisors n]
-- primeDivisors n is a list of the prime divisors of n

maxRatio :: (Int, Int, Double) -> (Int, Int, Double) -> (Int, Int, Double)
maxRatio t1@(_, _, x) t2@(_, _, y)
  | x > y = t1
  | otherwise = t2

main = print (foldl
                maxRatio
                (0, 0, 0.0)
                [(n, phi n, ratio) | n <- [2..max], let ratio = fromIntegral n / (fromIntegral (phi n))]
              )
    where max = 1000
```

which gives the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Integer'
In the expression: n
In the expression: (n, phi n, ratio)
In the third argument of `foldl', namely
  `[(n, phi n, ratio) |
      n <- [2 .. max],
      let ratio = fromIntegral n / (fromIntegral (phi n))]'
```

I suspect that in the triple `(0, 0, 0.0)` the 0's are type `Int`. Is `0` always type `Int` or is ghci deducing the type as `Int` in this case? If the later, how do I force it to be type `Integer` instead? Or is there something else that causes this error?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429291/what-is-the-difference-between-int-and-integer

Comment: @SolomonUcko Thanks for the link. I'm sure it will be helpful for future visitors to this page.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Haskell can generally infer the type of numeric literals such as `0` as whatever appropriate type you need them to be. This is because it knows what functions you pass them to; if I have a function `phi :: Integer -> Integer`, and I call `phi 0`, Haskell knows that that particular `0` must have been an `Integer`. It's also fine if I call a function `pho :: Int -> Int` with `pho 0`; *that* particular `0` is inferred to be an `Int`.

However `Int` and `Integer` are different types, and there's no way one particular `0` can be passed to both `phi` and `pho`.

Your issue is simply that the tuples that `maxRatio` deals with are typed (by you) `(Int, Int, Double)`, but that one such tuple is constructed as `(n, phi n, ratio)`. Since `phi` takes and returns `Integer`, the `n` in that expression has to be an `Integer`. But then that doesn't work for `maxRatio`, so you get the error.

Depending on which type you actually wanted (`Int` or `Integer`), all you need to do is change the type signature of `phi` or `maxRatio` so that they're working with the same kind of number. Haskell will decide that your literally written `0`s are whatever numeric type is necessary to make that work, *provided* there is one that **can** make it work!

Note that the error messaged *specifically* told you that it was `n` in `(n, phi n, ratio)` that was expected to be an `Int` and was actually an `Integer`. The `(0, 0, 0.0)` tuple is never mentioned. Often type errors originate somewhere other than where the compiler points you (since all the compiler can do is spot that different chains of inference produce inconsistent requirements on the type of something, with no way to know which part of the whole process is "wrong"), but in this case it did pretty well.

Haskell gets a (fairly justified) bad rep for inscrutable error messages, but it can help a lot to start from what the compiler is telling you is the problem and try to figure out **why** the facts it's complaining about arise from your code. This will be painful at first, but you'll quickly develop a basic literacy in Haskell's error messages (at least the more straightforward ones) that will help you spot these kinds of errors really quickly, which makes the compiler a very powerful error-detection system for you.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I thought that `0` was polymorphic in its type, but my noob eyes couldn't see any other reason for the type inference that gave the error. Of course, I simply missed my explicit type declaration for `maxRatio`.

Answer (score 5):

`n` is being inferred as `Int` due to the type of `maxRatio`, while the type of `phi` says it should be `Integer`. The simplest fix is to change the type of `maxRatio` to use `Integer` or even just `a` since it doesn't touch those values.

Comment: Doh! I missed that detail. I am revisiting some code that I wrote a while back probably before I learned to use Integer almost exclusively.

Answer (score 3):

It's being inferred, so you can just change the type signature of `maxRatio`. Still, if you ever need to change an explicit `Int` to an `Integer`, use `toInteger :: (Integral a) => a -> Integer`

Comment: I usually use `fromIntegeral`, especially when I'm using `length`. Is there a difference between using `fromIntegral` rather than `toInteger`?

Comment: @Code-Guru: I think the only difference is that `fromIntegral` can return any `Num` type, so it's a little less clear when reading it what type it's going to be inferred as.

Comment: @Code-Guru: actually, `fromIntegral` is defined as `fromIntegral = fromInteger . toInteger` -- so it's definitely just a tradeoff between flexibility and readability

Answer (score 1):

Your type signatures are inconsistent - replace `Int` with `Integer` throughout.