# What is the upper bound of Integer in Haskell?

Tags: math, haskell

I was solving a math problem: want to get the sum of the digits of the number `2^1000`.

In Java, the solution is like:

```
String temp = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(1000).toString();

int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++)
    sum += temp.charAt(i) - '0';
```

Then came up a solution in Haskell, like this:

```
digitSum ::(Integral a) => a -> a                  
digitSum 0 = 0
digitSum n = (mod n 10) + (digitSum (div n 10))
```

The whole process is pretty smooth, one point seems interesting, we know integer type can not handle `2 ^ 1000`, too big, in Java, it's obvious to use `BigInteger` and treat the big number to string, but in Haskell, no compiling errors means the `2 ^ 1000` could be passed in directly. Here is the thing, does Haskell transform the number into string internally? I want to  make sure what the type is and let the compiler to determine, then I type the following lines in *GHCi*:

```
Prelude> let i = 2 ^ 1000

Prelude> i 
107150860718626732094842504906000181056140481170553360744375038837035105112493612249319
837881569585812759467291755314682518714528569231404359845775746985748039345677748242309
854210746050623711418779541821530464749835819412673987675591655439460770629145711964776
86542167660429831652624386837205668069376

Prelude> :t i
i :: Integer
```

Here, I was totally confused, apparently, the number of `i` is oversized, but the return type of  `i`  is still `Integer`. How could we explain this and what's the upper bound  or limit of `Integer` of Haskell?

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429291/haskell-int-and-integer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Haskell, `Integer` is a - theoretically - unbounded integer type. Fixed-width types are `Int`, `Int8`, `Int16`, `Int32`, `Int64` and the corresponding unsigned `Word`, `Word8` etc.

In practice, even `Integer` is of course bounded, by the available memory for instance, or by the internal representation.

By default, GHC uses the GMP package to represent `Integer`, and that means the bound is `2^(2^37)` or so, since GMP uses a 32-bit integer to store the number of limbs.