# Why do large number operations return negative numbers at a certain point with 'ints' in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, numbers, int

With the following function:
`factorial :: Int -> Int`
`factorial n = product [1..n]`

The correct value is returned with parameters less than 21. For example:
`factorial 20` returns 2432902008176640000, but `factorial 21` returns -4249290049419214848 which isn't correct even if the value wasn't negative.

I know that with these size numbers `Integer` should have been utilized, but where specifically is the error occurring here and why?

Comment: [Integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429291/haskell-int-and-integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Int` in Haskell is a fixed-precision representation of the integers with a finite range. As is the case with most fixed-precision integer representations, an arithmetic operation that would create an integer that is too large or small to be represented (which is called an *integer overflow*, as mentioned by Mephy) will have its result *wrapped* by truncating it to its least significant bits. For example:

```
λ> maxBound + 1 :: Int
-9223372036854775808

λ> (maxBound + 1 :: Int) == minBound
True
```